# In Magento site ,My checkout button is broken

Tags: magento

not sure why my magento site
all links broken, My check out button link showing me like this error

```
 <form "="" getformkey="" varnishcache="" www.alphacateringequipment.com.au="" https:="" action="https://www.alphacateringequipment.com.au/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWxwaGFjYXRlcmluZ2VxdWlwbWVudC5jb20uYXUvYmV2ZXJhZ2UvYWNjZXNzb3JpZXM,/product/3704/form_key/&lt;esi:include src=">/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_3704"&gt;
                          <button onclick="productAddToCartForm_3704.submit()" class="form-button listing_cart-btn">ADD TO Cart</button>
             </form>
```

and also my site drop down menu not working more 
if any one know this 
Please help me out.

thank you

Comment: check your code.I think you miss either single or double starting or ending.then code creates such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 <form name="text" getformkey="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();  ?>" varnishcache="" www.alphacateringequipment.com.au="" https:="" action="https://www.alphacateringequipment.com.au/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWxwaGFjYXRlcmluZ2VxdWlwbWVudC5jb20uYXUvYmV2ZXJhZ2UvYWNjZXNzb3JpZXM,/product/3704/form_key/&lt;esi:include src=">/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_3704"&gt;

      <button onclick="productAddToCartForm_3704.submit()" class="form-button listing_cart-btn">ADD TO Cart</button>
 </form>
```

It will broken due to form key not passed by In Version of Magento.

Comment: How can i solve this? My drop down menu also not working

Comment: you have purchase any custom theme?

Comment: No,we implemented this theme

Comment: then check like some conflict arise due to your code or check if you have install any custom extension